# Не работают функции slideDown и fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

По идее должно делать плавную анимацию и при загрузке плавно появляться, но выдает ошибку, что slideDown и fadeOut не являются функцией.

```js
$(function() {
  $('h2').hide().slideDown();
  var $li = $('li');
  $li.hide().each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(700 * index).fadeIn(700);
  });
  $li.on('click', function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(700);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
  <h1 id="header">Список</h1>
  <h2>Подсписок</h2>
  <ul>
    <li id="one" class="hot">Текст 1</li>
    <li id="two" class="hot">Текст 2</li>
    <li id="three" class="hot">Текст 3</li>
    <li id="four">Текст 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Вроде работает...

Comment: Порядок подключения скриптов какой?

Comment: перезапустите браузер или почистите кеш, ошибок нет в гугл, когда запускаю

Comment: в хроме,то есть...